# How to set FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING in Saxon's config or command line for Oxygen editor?

Tags: saxon, oxygenxml

I couldn't find a way to enable `FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING` in Oxygen XML Developer or through Saxon's config file.

How can I enable it without writing Java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING` is an XML parser feature rather than a Saxon feature per se.

In 9.6 we've introduced a way to set XML parser features as if they were Saxon features using (in this case) the URI

```
http://saxon.sf.net/feature/parserFeature?uri=http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing
```

However, I don't think there is any way to set this from a configuration file or from oXygen without writing any Java code. The simplest way would be to write a little Initializer class that sets the property, and specify this Initializer in your oXygen scenario.

Comment: That's what I did here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428883/layer-7-xslt1-0-and-xslt2-0-compatibility?noredirect=1#comment47027878_29428883 :-)