# Layer 7 XSLT1.0 and XSLT2.0 compatibility

Tags: java, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

We are using Layer7 which is an ESB featuring XML transformation with the help of XSLT1 and XSLT2.

They use XALAN and Saxon 9.4.0.4 but they enable the FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING flag.

For my tests I use a dedicated TransformerFactory class like this :

```
package company.transformer.factory;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl;;


public class TransformerFactory extends TransformerFactoryImpl   {

    @Override
    public Transformer newTransformer(Source arg0)
            throws TransformerConfigurationException {
        this.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING,true);
        Transformer t=super.newTransformer(arg0);       
        return t;
    }

    @Override
    public Transformer newTransformer()
            throws TransformerConfigurationException {
        this.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING,true);
        Transformer t=super.newTransformer();
        return t;
    }   

}
```

When using XSLT2, I can use "xsl:function" but once deployed on the ESB, this is ignored without making any error !

Can anyone tell me what is really supported by Layer7 in regard of XSLT1 and XSLT2 ?

Comment: Deployed on the USB???

Comment: @leppie ESB of course !

Comment: If the `xsl:function` is ignores then it can mean that for some reason the transformer is not set to use Saxon and that XSLT 1.0 is ignoring the declaration (as it should), however, you should receive an error on the call to the function. Another reason is perhaps way simpler: the template containing your function is never triggered on the server (different data, different namespaces). The `FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING` has no effect on the use of `xsl:function`.